# What military aeroplane seen at Prestwick is this?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

I saw this plane flying out from Prestwick airport yesterday but what is it?

[image: Photograph of unidentified 4 engine airplane]

Comment: Also see: [Are 'aircraft identification' questions using photos eligible for duplicate voting?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3770/14897)

Answer (score 10):

Based on the fact that this looks like a 4-engined jet, with a T-tail, and winglets. I think it is a C-17.

[image: From wikipedia, C-17 deploying paratroops]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:8th_Airlift_Squadron_C-17A_Globemaster_III_90-0535.jpg))

Comment: Number of Küchemann bodies also matches, and the ramp might be identifiable as well. Looks like the correct answer.

Comment: It's also got the landing gear in fairings under the fuselage, which is a common setup for military transports (to keep the inside load space wide for the full length).  A little sub-fin also helps agreement with this type.

Comment: C-17's fly in and out of Prestwick regularly. Prestwick has the longest commercial runway in Scotland (Macrihanish is longer) so it's a useful facility for exceedingly large cargo aircraft.

Comment: And the C-17 is the only four-engined jet cargo aircraft flown by the RAF. (Of course, we don't know from the picture that this is an RAF plane.)

Answer (score 4):

It's a C17.

> RCH560 C17 08-8193 arrived off the ocean about 0225L

As taken from [this forum](https://www.fightercontrol.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=175467&sid=553efb44d818251e33ed2c0afcca0549)

Comment: Good find! RCH has the callsign Reach and is commonly used for USAF C-17 flights.